# Insert into and merge of data between two SQL Servers on different PCs on the same network

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, network-programming

I was wondering how to append data from a SQL Server database to another on a second computer. I've already used the `MERGE` method by setting the source and target table from the same SQL Server but this time the case is different. I'm trying to retrieve records from 2 standalone POS machines in a grocery stores to the server.

Is there any easy way to achieve this? Is a SQL Server stored procedure using the computer's name or ip address the way to go?

Comment: Just use [linked servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have solved this problem on many projects and it depends on the scenario of your synchronization, whether it is a manual or automated etc.

In one project, we finally programmed our own synchronization service in .NET. But today we prefer products that offer this functionality out-of-the-box. I personally have experience with DevArt Data Compare, which works great, can be automated and can synchronize data from multiple sources into one (https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/datacompare/). In our case, we used it to synchronize from a production server to several test servers via Data Compare and it is orchestrated from one asset.

In addition to Data Compare we also used SymmetricDS (https://github.com/JumpMind/symmetric-ds) which is now unmaintained and is offered in a commercial version (https://www.jumpmind.com/products/symmetricds/overview). It is definitely a good tool but for us the Data Compare from DevArt was better in terms of price and it is able to solve most synchronization scenarios for a good price.

Regards.

Comment: linked servers worked for me, but will take a look at those links too.

Comment: Linked servers are not a solution for data synchronization. It's about server connectivity, but it's not related to the schema and data layer. All this work must be coded. In addition, Microsoft wants to leave Linked servers in the future and considers them an obsolete feature. (https://www.sswug.org/bentaylor/editorials/linked-servers-are-going-away-2/).